# How do I get specific information from a registered user and display it in my app in Kotlin with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, formatting

I'm new to Kotlin and Firebase, I want this to happen:

When a registered user logs in with his Email and Password, I want to display the Complete Name (User has to input complete name upon registering) connected to that Email in my dashboard (new activity), How do I do it?

Relevant Codes:
MainActivity.kt:

```
lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    if (currentUser != null) {
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, dashboard::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
    login()
}

private fun login() {
    loginButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailLogin.text.toString())) {
            emailLogin.error = "Please enter registered email."
            return@setOnClickListener
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordLogin.text.toString())) {
            passwordLogin.error = "Please enter password."
            return@setOnClickListener
        }
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailLogin.text.toString(), passwordLogin.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, dashboard::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Login failed, please try again! ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            }

    }
```

dashboard.kt (idk if this is relevant):

```
lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
var database: FirebaseDatabase? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

    val actionBar = supportActionBar
    actionBar!!.title = "Dashboard"

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    databaseReference = database?.reference!!.child("profile")

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close)
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.profile -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.settings -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Clicked Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            R.id.logoutButton -> logout()
        }
        true
    }
}

    private fun logout() {
        auth.signOut()
        startActivity(Intent(this@dashboard, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
```

I want the complete name to be displayed in this:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/completeNameDisplay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="132dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/dashboard_modules"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="25dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Registration snippet:

```
private fun register(){
    registerButton.setOnClickListener {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(fullNameRegister.text.toString())) {
                fullNameRegister.setError("Please enter full name")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumberRegister.text.toString())) {
                phoneNumberRegister.setError("Please enter a valid phone number")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(passwordRegister.text.toString())) {
                passwordRegister.setError("Please enter password")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(regionRegister.text.toString())) {
                passwordRegister.setError("Please enter Region")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(cityRegister.text.toString())) {
                passwordRegister.setError("Please enter City")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(address1Register.text.toString())) {
                passwordRegister.setError("Please enter address")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(address2Register.text.toString())) {
                passwordRegister.setError("Please enter address")
                return@setOnClickListener
            } else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(emailRegister.text.toString())) {
                passwordRegister.setError("Please enter email")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailRegister.text.toString(), passwordRegister.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener{
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
                    val currentUSerDb = databaseReference?.child((currentUser?.uid!!))
                    currentUSerDb?.child("Fullname")?.setValue(fullNameRegister.text.toString())
                    Toast.makeText(this@registration, "Registration Success! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    finish()

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@registration, "Registration failed, please try again! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors at all, I want to know how to display the name.

Comment: So what exactly in all these lines of code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: My code is working perfectly, but I want to display the registered Complete Name of the email that was used to log in to the `TextView` code snippet that I pasted.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, it sounds like the code is working as you expect. In that case, I'm going to assume that the user is registered with Firebase Auth upon log in. If that's true, you should be able to access the current user as discussed in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
user?.let {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    val name = user.displayName
    val email = user.email
    val photoUrl = user.photoUrl

    // Check if user's email is verified
    val emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    val uid = user.uid
}
```